# Simplifying Trignometric Identities

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have a trignometric solution of the form,

$A Cos(x) + B Sin(x)$

I want to make it into something of the form,

$C Sin(x + \delta)$

Where $C$ and $\delta$ are given in terms of A and B

Comment: [Possible dupe.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30389)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr1 = a Cos[x] + b Sin[x];

expr2 = c Sin[x + d];

expr3 = expr2 // TrigExpand

(*  c Cos[x] Sin[d] + c Cos[d] Sin[x]  *)
```

Equating coefficients and requiring `a != 0`, `c` and `d` are given by

```
sol = Solve[{a == Coefficient[expr3, Cos[x]],
     b == Coefficient[expr3, Sin[x]], a != 0}, {c, d}, Reals] /. C[1] -> 0 // 
  Simplify

(*  {{c -> -a Csc[2 ArcTan[b/a + Sqrt[1 + b^2/a^2]]], 
  d -> -2 ArcTan[b/a + Sqrt[1 + b^2/a^2]]}, {c -> -a Csc[
     2 ArcTan[b/a - Sqrt[1 + b^2/a^2]]], 
  d -> -2 ArcTan[b/a - Sqrt[1 + b^2/a^2]]}}  *)
```

`expr2` is then

```
expr2 /. sol

(*  {-a Csc[2 ArcTan[b/a + Sqrt[1 + b^2/a^2]]] Sin[
   x - 2 ArcTan[b/a + Sqrt[1 + b^2/a^2]]], -a Csc[
   2 ArcTan[b/a - Sqrt[1 + b^2/a^2]]] Sin[
   x - 2 ArcTan[b/a - Sqrt[1 + b^2/a^2]]]}  *)
```

Each simplifies to `expr1`

```
% // FullSimplify

(*  {a Cos[x] + b Sin[x], a Cos[x] + b Sin[x]}  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are special Trig functions that attempt to do these kinds of transformations:

```
TrigExpand[c Sin[x + d]]
c Cos[x] Sin[d] + c Cos[d] Sin[x]

TrigReduce[c Cos[x] Sin[d] + c Cos[d] Sin[x]]
c Sin[d + x]
```

For the particular form you requested, you'll want to collect the coefficients with the same trig functions

```
red = TrigReduce[a Cos[x] Sin[d] + b Cos[d] Sin[x]]
Collect[red, {Sin[d - x], Sin[d + x]}]
1/2 (a - b) Sin[d - x] + 1/2 (a + b) Sin[d + x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica seems to have difficulties to get to your form, as it is only valid for real values, and MMA generally doesn't like equations over `Reals` as much as those over `Complexes`.

Anyway, the solution is $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(x+\arctan(b,a))$: (if someone manages to get MMA to find this "on its own", I'd be very interested)

```
In[1]:= TrigExpand[Sqrt[A^2 + B^2] Sin[x + ArcTan[B, A]]]
Out[1]= A Cos[x] + B Sin[x]
```