# Change general solution form of the simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: differential-equations

When I try to solve the simple harmonic oscillator equation

```
DSolve[y''[x] + k*y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

the solution is given by:

```
{{y[x] -> C[1] Cos[Sqrt[k] x] + C[2] Sin[Sqrt[k] x]}}
```

How can I get the general solution in the form

```
{{y[x] -> C[1] Cos[Sqrt[k] x + C[2]]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple trigonometric simplification.

```
soly = DSolve[{y''[x] + k y[x] == 0, y[0] == c0 Cos[phi0], y'[0] == c0 Sqrt[k] Sin[phi0]}, y, x][[1]] /. {c0 -> C[1], phi0 -> -C[2]}
yx = y[x] /. soly // TrigReduce

(* C[1] Cos[Sqrt[k] x + C[2]] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I cheated a little here.

Btw, I do not think your formula is correct. It should be

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(page 167, Differential equations and their applications, 4th edition. By Braun).

Hence, you can do

```
ClearAll[x,y,k];
sol=y[x]/.First@DSolve[y''[x]+k*y[x]==0,y[x],x];
convert[sol,k,x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where

```
convert[sol_, k_, x_] := Module[{a, b, expr},
  expr = TrigExpand[sol];
  b = CoefficientList[expr, Cos[Sqrt[k] x], 2][[2]];
  a = CoefficientList[expr, Sin[Sqrt[k] x], 2][[2]];
  Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Cos[Sqrt[k] x - ArcTan[b, a]]
  ]
```

Reference: [Combining cosine or sine terms into a single cosine or sine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30389/combining-cosine-or-sine-terms-into-a-single-cosine-or-sine/30393#30393)